# two boot loaders. want the original one

Tags: grub2, bootloader, elementary

I just installed elementary OS to my PC alongside with Ubuntu 13.04.

```
sdb1 - Ubuntu
sdb4 - eOS
```

My problem is that Ubuntu's grub has been overwritten.. and the new one boots by default into eOS. How can I re-install Ubuntu's grub? (Ubuntu's grub hides old kernels and boots into Ubuntu default)

Comment: Does it display the grub menu at all or does it directly boot into eOS?

Answer (score 4):

Open your grub configuration file by typing in the terminal

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

When this the opens, check that the following lines in your file look like this-

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

if not edit them to look like above.

What this will do is to enable your Grub menu at boot time and give you a time of 5 seconds to choose an OS.

Then save the file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should now list your eOS as well as Ubuntu13.04

This should be enough.

Now you would be able to boot into Ubuntu 13.04 on restart.

However if you still want 
To get the Ubuntu bootloader back, boot into Ubuntu, open a terminal and type-

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
sudo update-grub
```

This would install Ubuntu's grub to the MBR of sdb and update the grub configuration file.

Comment: You are welcome. If it helped you, please mark this as solved.